# How to get the current running function name when declared with "foo = function(){...}"?

Tags: javascript

In this situation, arguments.callee.name get nothing.

```
foo = function(){
  console.log(arguments.callee.name);
}
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: The solution is correct. Your function has no name.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Argument callee is black magic and won't work in strict mode.

Comment: Why do you need the name of the function?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/28260389/1048572, which details why this isn't even *possible*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't name it, thus it has no name.

```
foo = function(){
  return (arguments.callee.name);
};

bar = function foobar() {
  return (arguments.callee.name);
};

function foobar () {
  return (arguments.callee.name);
}

console.log(foo()); //""
console.log(bar()); //"foobar"
console.log(foobar()) //"foobar"
```

The difference between `foo()` and `foobar()` is that `foo()` is a function expression, whereas `foobar()` is a declared function. The difference between `foo()` and `bar()` and is that one has a name, the other doesn't. Both are function expressions. Declared functions need a name, function expressions do not. See this canonical question for more info:

[var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)