# Private field access with class inheritance

Tags: javascript, class

I have a menu. It uses a peer class of **MenuItem** to create and validate menu items:

```
export class MenuItem {
  constructor(data) {
    const { name, price, stock = 0, description = "", tags = [] } = data;
    // log(arguments);

    // Defensive Checks for validation go here...

    this._id = String(Math.random());
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.stock = stock;
    this.description = description;
    this.tags = tags;
  }
  someMethod() {
    console.log("blah...");
  }
}
```

The **Menu** class itself looks like this:

```
export default class Menu {
  #items = []; // Now a private field, so you can't tamper with it from outside this class
  constructor(itemsDataArray = []) {
    if (!Array.isArray(itemsDataArray)) {
      throw new Error(`Items must be an array. Received ${itemsDataArray} (${typeof itemsDataArray})`);
    }

    for (const itemData of itemsDataArray) {
      this.#items.push(new MenuItem(itemData));
    }
  }

  // GET ALL items
  getAllItems() {
    console.log("superclass getAllItems", this);
    return this.#items.slice(); // return a copy, so it can't be affected outside
  }
}
```

This makes a fine READ menu.

I want to inherit this to make a sub-class of **EditableMenu**

```
export default class EditableMenu extends Menu {
  constructor(itemsDataArray = []) {
    super(itemsDataArray);
  }

  // CREATE an item
  addItem(itemData) {

    if (!itemData) {
      throw new Error(`No data provided to addItem: received ${itemData}`);
    }

    // Create a new item
    const newItem = new MenuItem(itemData);

    
    // push it into our internal array
    this.#items.push(newItem);

    // Return the finished product for reference
    return { ...newItem };
  }
}
```

I made the array of items private in the superclass so that it can't be edited directly but now I just get the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#items' must be declared in an enclosing class`

Any ideas about how I could approach this. I understand that this is likely syntactic sugar over closures and I wouldn't be sure how to pass a reference between classes without making the array public in the superclass?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jmsherry/pen/ExPGwML?editors=0012)

Comment: It was answered already in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61237892/11215806

Comment: Private fields are really that, private. You cannot access them from anywhere else, and not from subclasses either. If you want to use inheritance, use a normal property (with an underscore prefix as a hint maybe).